# Как изменить кнопку из слушателя

Tags: eclipse, java

Вот, собственно и все. Код:
UPD:

```
public class Standart implements ActionListener{
JButton But1;

Standart(String name, String size){
    JFrame jfrm=new JFrame(name);
    JButton But1=new JButton("B1");
    But1.addActionListener(this);
    jfrm.add(But1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jfrm.pack();
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    But1.setBorderPainted(true);
    But1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);   
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("B1")){
        But1.setText("Pressed");

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new Standart("reb","ver");
    }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быть может, нужно заменить

```
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("B1")){
```

на

```
if(ae.getText().equals("B1")){
```

---

**UPD0.**

Итоговый результат и разбор полетов:

```
public Standard(String name, String size){
    JFrame jfrm=new JFrame(name);
    But1=new JButton("B1"); // тут вы объявляли локальную переменную JButton But1, она перекрывала видимость поля But1 самого объекта
    But1.addActionListener(this); //Да, неплохо бы прикрепить к кнопке обработчик; то что у вас есть метод actionPerformed еще не значит, что туда будут отправляться события. Сам класс Standart должен имплементировать интерфейс ActionListener.
    jfrm.add(But1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jfrm.pack();
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    // впрочем тут сработает и ваш вариант с getActionCommand()
    if(((JButton)ae.getSource()).getText().equals("B1")){
        But1.setText("Pressed"); // does nothing

    }
}
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: @iamqwerty, обновил ответ.

Comment: Как можно было забыть прикрепить обработчик?!
Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Еще раз повторю: обратите внимание на строчку:

    JButton But1=new JButton("B1");

и на то как она у меня написана:

    But1=new JButton("B1");

В вашем случае вы вешаете обработчик на кнопку, хранящуюся в локальной переменной конструктора. А в обработчике устанавливаете текст кнопке, хранящейся в поле класса (которая не инициализирована, и очевидно, вы получаете `NPE`).

Comment: Спасибо, получилось